# Why is my DSharpPlus Slash Command not playing my desired sound using FFMPEG in C#?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm having a problem with my ffmpeg setup the commands work fine but my play command doesn't play my desired sound.

```
//The command.
        [SlashCommand("play", "plays a sound in a voice channel.")]
        public async Task HowlCommand(InteractionContext ctx, [Choice("ChoiceName", "C:\\My\\Program\\Directory\\Name\\MySound.mp3")]
                                                             [Option("Sound", "Please select a Sound")] string filepath)
        {
            //Creates a slash command used response.
            //Also removes the error message.
            await ctx.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.ChannelMessageWithSource, new DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder()
                                                                                                                    .WithContent("Playing sound in voice channel. Please wait just a moment!"));
 
            //Checks if the user is not a bot to send the message.
            if (ctx.Member.IsBot)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if(filepath != "C:\\My\\Program\\Directory\\Name\\MySound.mp3")
                {
                    var embedmessage = new DiscordMessageBuilder()
                        .AddEmbed(new DiscordEmbedBuilder()
 
                        .WithAuthor("BotName", null, ctx.Client.CurrentApplication.Icon)
                        .WithTitle("Please select the following sound to play:")
                        .WithImageUrl(ctx.Client.CurrentApplication.Icon)
                        .WithFooter("VoiceChannel Error.", "ImageURL.png")
                        .WithTimestamp(DateTime.Now)
                        .Build()
 
                        );
 
                    //Makes the command wait 5 seconds before sending the rest of the command data.
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
 
                    //Sends the embed in a message.
                    await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(embedmessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Makes the command wait 5 seconds before sending the rest of the command data.
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
 
 
                    var vnext = ctx.Client.GetVoiceNext();
                    var vnc = vnext.GetConnection(ctx.Guild);
                    
                    //if null throws exception.
                    if (vnc == null)
                        throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Not connected in this guild.");
 
 
                    //Gets the mp3 file to use.
                    var ffmpeg = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = "ffmpeg",
                        Arguments = $@"-i ""{filepath}"" -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false
                    });
                    Stream pcm = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
 
                    VoiceTransmitSink transmit = vnc.GetTransmitSink();
                    await pcm.CopyToAsync(transmit);
                    vnc.GetTransmitSink().VolumeModifier = 5;
 
                    //Makes the command wait 10 seconds before sending the rest of the command data.
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
 
                    //Disconnects the bot from the voice channel.
                    vnc.Disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
```

```
//The command.
        [SlashCommand("join", "Joins a voice channel.")]
        public async Task JoinChannel(InteractionContext ctx, [Choice("MyVoiceChannel", "VoiceChannelName")]
                                                             [Option("VoiceChannel", "Please choose a Voice Channel.")] DiscordChannel channel)
        {
            //Creates a slash command used response.
            //Also removes the error message.
            await ctx.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.ChannelMessageWithSource, new DiscordInteractionResponseBuilder()
                                                                                                                    .WithContent("Joining voice channel. Please wait just a moment!"));
 
            //Checks if the user is not a bot to send the message.
            if (ctx.Member.IsBot)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (channel.Name != "MyVoiceChannelName")
                {
                    var embedmessage = new DiscordMessageBuilder()
                        .AddEmbed(new DiscordEmbedBuilder()
 
                        .WithAuthor("BotName", null, ctx.Client.CurrentApplication.Icon)
                        .WithTitle("Please Create The Following Voice Channel:")
                        .WithImageUrl(ctx.Client.CurrentApplication.Icon)
                        .AddField("VoiceChannel:", "**BotName**" + Environment.NewLine + "Is Case Sensitive: **Yes**")
                        .WithFooter("VoiceChannel Error.", "ImageURL.png")
                        .WithTimestamp(DateTime.Now)
                        .Build()
 
                        );
 
                    //Makes the command wait 5 seconds before sending the rest of the command data.
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
 
                    //Sends the embed in a message.
                    await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(embedmessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Makes the command wait 5 seconds before sending the rest of the command data.
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
 
 
                    channel = ctx.Member.VoiceState?.Channel;
                    await channel.ConnectAsync();
 
                }
            }
        }
 
    }
}
```

```
public sealed class Program
    {
        public static DiscordClient Client { get; private set; }
        public static InteractivityExtension Interactivity { get; private set; }
        public static CommandsNextExtension Commands { get; private set; }
        public static VoiceNextExtension VoiceNext { get; private set; }
 
 
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
 
            //Main Window configs specifying the title name and color.
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.Title = "BotName";
 
            //1. Get the details of your config.json file by deserialising it
            var configJsonFile = new JSONReader();
            await configJsonFile.ReadJSON();
 
            //2. Setting up the Bot Configuration
            var discordConfig = new DiscordConfiguration()
            {
                Intents = DiscordIntents.All,
                Token = configJsonFile.token,
                TokenType = TokenType.Bot,
                AutoReconnect = true
            };
 
            //3. Apply this config to our DiscordClient
            Client = new DiscordClient(discordConfig);
 
            //4. Set the default timeout for Commands that use interactivity
            Client.UseInteractivity(new InteractivityConfiguration()
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
            });
 
            //5. Set up the Task Handler Ready event
            Client.Ready += OnClientReady;
 
            //6. Set up the Commands Configuration
            var commandsConfig = new CommandsNextConfiguration()
            {
                StringPrefixes = new string[] { configJsonFile.prefix },
                EnableMentionPrefix = true,
                EnableDms = true,
                EnableDefaultHelp = false,
            };
 
            Commands = Client.UseCommandsNext(commandsConfig);
 
            //7. Register your commands
            var slashCommandsConfig = Client.UseSlashCommands();
            slashCommandsConfig.RegisterCommands<MySoundsCommand>(MyGuildID);
 
            //8. Allows usage of voice channels.
            var VoiceNext = Client.UseVoiceNext();
 
            //9. Connect to get the Bot online
            await Client.ConnectAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }
 
        private static Task OnClientReady(DiscordClient sender, ReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

## SourceCode Link:

[text](https://pastebin.com/bx8mVW6Y)

playing the playsound slash command but wasn't expecting it to not play the mp3 file.

everything else worked fine except when it transmits the sound it doesn't play it.